# Undefined name x in selection clause even when x is stored

Tags: solr, lucene, datastax-enterprise

I'm creating a copied field with color synonyms from a color description field and this is working. I'm able to search using my copied field like this

```
/solr/my_keyspace.my_table/select?q=color_base:white
```

But the field is not showing up in the search results and if I add the field to the field list like this

```
/solr/my_keyspace.my_table/select?q=color_base:white&fl=color_base
```

I get the error

```
Undefined name color_base in selection clause
```

Here is my schema - I thought **stored="true"** would do the trick but it's not. I just want to see the field **color_base** in the search results.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<schema name="autoSolrSchema" version="1.5">
    <types>
        <fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.TextField" name="ColorField">
            <analyzer>
                <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="color_synonyms.txt" tokenizerFactory="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
            </analyzer>
        </fieldType>
        <fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.StrField" name="StrField"/>
    </types>
    <fields>
        <field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="color_description" stored="true" type="StrField" docValues="true"/>
        <field indexed="true" multiValued="true" name="color_base" stored="true" type="ColorField" docValues="true"/>
        <copyField source="color_description" dest="color_base"/>
    </fields>
    <uniqueKey>(year, make, base_model)</uniqueKey>
</schema>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I can't add search results using analyzers which was my goal. The analyzers are only for improving the searching capability but results cannot be modified by Solr. I had to add a new field to the underlying db (Cassandra) and map the values I wanted into it. Lesson learned - Solr is for searching ONLY, not for changing/updating/appending result sets.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like this is an issue in DSE. But, if you just want to get the color_base returned, you can get exactly the same result by asking color_description to be returned:

```
/solr/my_keyspace.my_table/select?q=color_base:white&fl=color_description
```

Even if color_description and color_base are different types, the stored value is the original value sent to Solr, not what results after the analysis, so you will get the same data by asking for any of them.

EDIT: about your comment...you should be able to facet on the analyzed value:

```
    /select?q=your query&facet=true&facet.field=color_base
```

But I cannot test this right now, I don't have any copyField in my DSE schema, try and hopefully you don't hit a similar issue as with fl...

Comment: That's what I've been seeing - so I guess I'm trying to retrieve the result of the analyzer. Is this not possible? I want the synonyms to show up in the search result.

Comment: The end goal for me is to facet on the analyzed tokens - is there any way to do this?